# Making a simple app that logs and reads in command line arguments with Visual Studio 2010 Express, google glog and google gflags?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I've written the following simple program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <gflags/gflags.h>
#include <glog/logging.h>
#include <ostream>
int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);


    LOG(INFO) << "Found";
    return 0;
}
```

I checked out google-glog from here: http://code.google.com/p/google-glog/source/checkout

And I've checked out google-gflags from here: http://code.google.com/p/google-gflags/

I have all three of these projects in Visual Studio 2010 Express, all under the same solution:

- Solution

  - **GoogleLibsTest**
  - libgflags
  - libglog

When I compile it, I get the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: GoogleLibsTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>GoogleLibsTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall google::LogMessage::~LogMessage(void)" (__imp_??1LogMessage@google@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
1>GoogleLibsTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall google::LogMessage::stream(void)" (__imp_?stream@LogMessage@google@@QAEAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
1>GoogleLibsTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const *,int)" (__imp_??0LogMessage@google@@QAE@PBDH@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>GoogleLibsTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl google::InitGoogleLogging(char const *)" (__imp_?InitGoogleLogging@google@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>C:\Users\leeand00\Desktop\glogNgflagsTest\GoogleLibsTest\Debug\GoogleLibsTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've done several things to try and fix this including:

- In the Solution Property page Selecting Common Properties Project>Dependencies and setting the GoogleLibsTest to depend on the other two projects.
- In the GoogleLibsTest Property page

  - Adding libgflags-debug.lib libglog_static.lib to the Configuration Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies list.
  - In Configuration Properties>VC++ Directories I added the directory containing libgflags-debug.lib and libglog_static.lib to the list of library directories.
  - In Configuration Properties>C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories added the paths to the <glog-base-dir>\src\windows (since this is where the header files are for glog)
  - In Configuration Properties>C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories added the paths to the <gflags-base-dir>\src\windows (since this is where the header files are for gflags)

For some reason it is looking for a dll file (I don't know why that is)

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: I'm trying to use glog with visual studio 2012, and have the same problem. I tried using the static library and the dll but I really can't figure out what's wrong. Did you make it work?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want to static link to glog, but forget to define "GOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL=" macro, just check out logging_unittest_static project shipped with glog.

Though I think there're some other problems when using glog with gflags on Windows. Check out [this link](http://code.google.com/p/google-glog/issues/detail?id=60)

Comment: Thanks, this works! In visual studio C/C++->Preprocessor paste down "GOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL=" (note the equal sign is included)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your project already has the "Additional Include Directories" set to src/windows of the GLOG project folder, then check the following:

1) Make sure that both GLOG and your app is compiled in either 32 or 64 bit (as of this date GLOG only seems to compile 64 bit in release mode)
2) Make sure that libglog.dll is in your system path
3) Make sure that libglog.lib is set in your project's "Additional Dependencies" (under Linker->Input)
4) Make sure that the path to libglog.lib is set in your project's "Additional Library Directories" (under Linker->General)